# How to sort null field values in Drupal?

Tags: nodes

I have a **content type** with one field of type text.

I add content for **5 nodes**.

For 2 nodes among 5, I entered nothing in text-field.

So scenario is 3 nodes have data in that field and **2 of the nodes are empty**.

Now I'm sorting on behalf of that particular text-field in my custom module and the result is:

**It hides node with empty content.**

**It means only 3 nodes are visible, empty values are not visible.**

**Expected result should be, the fields that don't have any value inside should also get sorted and the resulting nodes would be seen either at the top of all sort-able content or below it.**

*How can I achieve this?*

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by installing [Views Sort Null Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_sort_null_field) module.

> This module provides an additional sort for FieldAPI fields, which
>   sorts by whether the field is empty or not. This allows empty (i.e.
>   NULL) values in fields to be sorted last.

Comment: Actually I'm not using views module, it's my custom module where I'm rendering all nodes of certain content type in a block. And I have to sort these rendered nodes on basis of any field.

Comment: I _am_ using views to query and render a list of nodes, and this module worked a treat, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can may be do [ifnull](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function

```
IFNULL(node_data_field_value_some.field_important_value,0)  AS node_data_field_value_some_field_important_value
```